# Adding Event to blackberry calendar

Tags: events, blackberry, calendar

I try add an event to blackberry calendar. The following code is used:

```
EventList eventList = (EventList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.EVENT_LIST,PIM.WRITE_ONLY);
    _event = eventList.createEvent();

        String subject = _subject.getText().trim();
        String location = _location.getText().trim();
        long startTime = _startTime.getDate();
        long endTime = _endTime.getDate();
        String description = _desc.getText().trim();

        if (subject.length() == 0 || location.length() == 0)
        {
            Dialog.inform("Subject and location required");
            return false;
        }

        if ( endTime <= startTime || startTime < System.currentTimeMillis())
        {
            Dialog.inform("Invalid Start/End times");
            return false;
        }

        _event.addString(Event.SUMMARY, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, subject );
        _event.addString(Event.LOCATION, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, location);
        _event.addDate(Event.START, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, startTime);
        _event.addDate(Event.END, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, endTime);    
        _event.addString(Event.NOTE, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, description);

        RepeatRule rule = new RepeatRule();


        switch(_recur.getSelectedIndex())
        {
            case 1:
                rule.setInt(RepeatRule.FREQUENCY,RepeatRule.DAILY);
                break;

            case 2:
                rule.setInt(RepeatRule.FREQUENCY,RepeatRule.WEEKLY);
                break;

            case 3:
                rule.setInt(RepeatRule.FREQUENCY,RepeatRule.MONTHLY);
                break;

            case 4:
                rule.setInt(RepeatRule.FREQUENCY,RepeatRule.YEARLY);
                break;        
        }


        _event.setRepeat(rule);


        _event.commit();
```

This code is taken from Blackberry Sample Application PIMDEMO

**The error is :**

> The event added to the dates After the end date

Example:
If I set a event from 2011 Dec 1 (start date)to 2011 Dec 5(end date) Then the event shown in calendar from Dec 1 to all days after it(that is the event never ends).

I tested this code in simulator and BlackBerry pearl 9105.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Following `RepeatRule` Code and try.

```
 RepeatRule rule = new RepeatRule();


    switch(_recur.getSelectedIndex())
    {
        case 1:
            rule.setInt(RepeatRule.FREQUENCY,RepeatRule.DAILY);
            break;

        case 2:
            rule.setInt(RepeatRule.FREQUENCY,RepeatRule.WEEKLY);
            break;

        case 3:
            rule.setInt(RepeatRule.FREQUENCY,RepeatRule.MONTHLY);
            break;

        case 4:
            rule.setInt(RepeatRule.FREQUENCY,RepeatRule.YEARLY);
            break;        
    }


    _event.setRepeat(rule);
```

Comment: you have to add one option from where user select the repeat rule and then you will set that repeat rule.